# Deriving from HashAlgorithm in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, .net-core, hashalgorithm

In .NET Framework if we needed to create our own crypto algorithm we could create our own class like:

```
public class MyAlgorithm: System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm
{
}
```

But in .NET Core it seems very limited because of

```
public abstract class HashAlgorithm : IDisposable
    {     

    protected HashAlgorithm();    
    public virtual int HashSize { get; }    
    public byte[] ComputeHash(byte[] buffer);
    public byte[] ComputeHash(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);
    public byte[] ComputeHash(Stream inputStream);
    public void Dispose();
    public abstract void Initialize();
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing);
    protected abstract void HashCore(byte[] array, int ibStart, int cbSize);
    protected abstract byte[] HashFinal();
}
```

It doesn't have such things as `HashSizeValue` or `State`.

Should we still use `HashAlgorithm` as base class for own algorithms in .NET Core?

Comment: *our own crypto algorithm* You are creating a hash algorithm. It is different.

Comment: If you are building a hash algorithm from scratch, what use do you have for `HashSizeValue` (that is an unexposed property)? *you* are declaring what is the hash size of your algorithm, through the `HashSize` property. And for `State`... If you need a `State`, *you* keep the state.

Comment: @xanatos What I am actually doing I am porting the code from .NET Framework to .NET Core. Crypto algorithms there are using HashAlgorithm as base class. This is why I am asking

Comment: What is the correct way in .NET Core? Usage of some base class or no class?

Comment: The correct way is deriving from `HashAlgorithm`. Note that they (Microsoft) readded the two fields in November (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/861c91ef4815cc8f525049e83544d0872163f0d3) and in a previous version. If you need them you'll have to readd them. `State` is used by `TransformBlock`/`TransformFinalBlock` that the .NET Core 1.1 `HashAlgorithm` doesn't implement.

Comment: @xanatos The version on github you pointed out is ok, how can I use it if I build my application for .NET Core 1.1 in general? Will you post the answer if possible?

Comment: Readd the missing parts to your hash class. `State` and `HashValue` aren't used in the "base" `HashAlgorithm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class, implement a

```
public override int HashSize => 256;
```

(or the value you have).

If you are using `HashSizeValue`, change it to `HashSize`.

If you are using `State`, readd it as a `protected int State`. In the "full" `HashAlgorithm` it is used by two public methods (`TransformBlock` and `TransformFinalBlock`). If you need it (and you are using `TransformBlock` and `TransformFinalBlock`) then copy it from a newer version of .NET Core `HashAlgorithm` (you can find it on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives/src/System/Security/Cryptography/HashAlgorithm.cs)). If you were only checking it then you don't need it and you can comment it (because only two missing methods will be writing it).